# Why does creating a date variable in a data.frame remove the ability to expand the variable list in rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

When I create a date variable using lubridate I am unable to expand the variable list in the global environment pane of rstudio. Removing the date variable undoes this.

```r
# load the storms dataset from dplyr
library(dplyr)
data(storms)
```

The data.frame displays in the global environments window in rstudio with a small blue button that when clicked expands the data.frame displaying all the variables.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRQgC.jpg)

```r
# create a date variable by combining the month, day and year variables using 
# lubridate's mdy() function
library(lubridate)
storms <- mutate(storms, Date = mdy(paste(month, day, year)))
```

Now the little button is gone and the data.frame cannot be expanded. If the data.frame was previously expanded then it stays open and cannot be closed. 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHW03.jpg)

You can still click on the data.frame name as a shortcut to calling View() and the data opens in a new tab.

```r
# remove the date variable from the data.frame
storms <- select(storms, -Date)
```

Removing the Date Variable from the data.frame returns the little blue button. What's going on with this?

update: I'm using RStudio version 1.2.1335. Other users have experienced this issue: https://community.rstudio.com/t/environment-data-frames-expand-with-blue-arrow-but-tbl-dfs-dont/32566/20

Comment: Looks like a bug of `R studio 1.2.1335` and not something that has to do with a date column. Try this: `dt = data.frame(x=1:2, y=1:2)` and then this `dt = data.frame(x=1, y=1)`

Comment: Probably a better place for help would be this existing thread over at RStudio: https://community.rstudio.com/t/environment-data-frames-expand-with-blue-arrow-but-tbl-dfs-dont/32566/20. You should probably indicate exactly which version of RStudio you are using.

Comment: @AntoniosK yep that generates the same issue as well. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for the response. I'm using RStudio 1.2.1335. I'll update this question to reflect that. I'm glad to see I wasn't the only user experiencing this issue.

Comment: @QWalk it looks like for my example the arrow appears again if i do `dt = rbind(dt)`. But this is more like a hack. You can always use `str(dt)` to see in your console the info that the arrow provides. Or go back to the previous R studio version :)